# Java. Почему в классе Object у hashCode() и equals(Object obj) одна сигнатура?

Tags: java, объекты, hashcode, equals

Разбираясь с вариантами переопределения методов `hashCode()` и `equals(Object obj)` я захотел посмотреть что именно я переопределяю, то есть посмотреть тело методов, и когда залез в класс `Object` столкнулся с тем что там одни сигнатуры. А куда пропали тела? Где на них можно взглянуть? Помогите найти ...

p.s. детектив почти)))

Comment: Скорее всего вы просматриваете stub'ы, поставляемые с IDE, которые к реальной имплементации не имеют отношения. Сигнатура, между тем, является явно не тем, что вы описываете, потому что аргументы являются частью сигнатуры, и у этих двух методов они разные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для метода `equals` есть реализация на `java`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Метод `hashCode` же объявлен, как `native`, т.е. его реализация написана на c++. Вообще в oracle jvm существует несколько реализаций для этой функции. Чтобы выбрать какую то определенную, необходимо выставить флаг при старте jvm

```
-XX:hashCode=n
```

где n может быть:

> 0 – Park-Miller RNG (default)
>   1 – f(address, global_statement)
>   2 – constant 1
>   3 – Serial counter
>   4 – Object address
>   5 – Thread-local Xorshift

Видно, что по умолчанию выставлен генератор случайных чисел.
Посмотреть, как это реализовано на c++ можно по [ссылке](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/synchronizer.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

Следующие методы расположены в `Android/sdk/sources/android-X/java/lang` и к `Java/jdkX.X.X_X/src.zip;java/lang/` прямого отношения не имеют(*спасибо @Regent`у*)

`hashCode()` в классе `Object`

```
public int hashCode() {
    int lockWord = shadow$_monitor_;
    final int lockWordStateMask = 0xC0000000;  // Top 2 bits.
    final int lockWordStateHash = 0x80000000;  // Top 2 bits are value 2 (kStateHash).
    final int lockWordHashMask = 0x0FFFFFFF;  // Low 28 bits.
    if ((lockWord & lockWordStateMask) == lockWordStateHash) {
        return lockWord & lockWordHashMask;
    }
    return System.identityHashCode(this);
}
```

`equals(Object obj)` в классе `Object`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

Comment: А у меня в классе Object просто public native int hashCode(); на 100-ой строке. Где вам удалось его найти?

Comment: @Павел:  в Android Studio, F4 при фокусе на `Object`

Comment: Стоит отметить, что этот файл находится в папке _Android/sdk/sources/android-X/java/lang_, а не в _Java/jdkX.X.X_X/src.zip;java/lang/_, так что можно сказать, что в Android свой `Object`, с преферансом и мадемуазелями.

Comment: @Regent:  спасибо большое, буду знать